# Lagrange multiplier method. Really need help on this question !! :(

Tags: optimization, lagrange-multiplier

A firm produces a good using two raw materials, X and Y ,
and the corresponding costs per unit of these raw materials
are $C_x$ and $C_y$ , respectively. The amount of its good that a
firm can produce using x units of X and y of Y is $\sqrt{x}+ \sqrt{y}$.

Use the Lagrange multiplier method to find the minimum
combined cost, C, of raw materials X and Y which will
enable the firm to produce a total amount q of its good.

Find the value, b, of the Lagrange multiplier corresponding
to the optimising values of x and y. Show that b=∂C/∂q

I could not seem to find the constraint for the equation, can anyone enlighten me?I could only get the equation up till this point and I am not sure if I am on the right track.
$$
\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{y} - b(x C_x + y C_y -q) = 0
$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  You'll get a lot more help, and fewer votes to close, if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself.  What are your thoughts?  What have you tried?  How far did you get?  Where are you stuck?  This question is likely to be closed if you don't add more context.  Please respond by **editing the question body.**  Many people browsing questions will vote to close without reading the comments.

Comment: Just google "cobb douglas production lagrangian": https://mbounthavong.com/blog/2019/2/19/cobb-douglas-production-function-and-total-costs

Comment: I know about cobb douglas, but i cannot find the equation to start with for the question

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are looking to optimize the cost $C(x,y) = C_x x + C_y y$ subject to matching the total goods constraint $$\tag{*} q = \sqrt{x} + \sqrt{y}.$$

In that case, the Lagrangian is
$$
\mathcal{L}(x,y) = C_x x + C_y y - b \left(\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{y} - q\right)
$$
and you want to enforce $(*)$ as well.